# Angular Spartacus login page flashes after refresh any page on SSR mode

Tags: angular, authentication, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

How to prevent flashing/flickering of login page on every page refresh in Spartacus application in SSR mode.
I tried to

```
RouterModule.forRoot([], {
     initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
}),
```

but after this I get only blank page